# How to invert a simple exponential growth formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I think this is simple but my math skills are limited.
I have a basic exponential growth formula:
$$y=x \cdot (1-p)^n$$ and I have $y$ and $x$ and $n$ values and I need value of $p$.
Then when I solve for $p$, I have to calculate $y$ with different values of $n$.
It's easy for me to do that but than I get $y$ values that decreases fast and than slow like on this graph:

[image]

But I want to decrease slower and than faster like on this graph

[image]

How to change the beginning formula to get what I said?

Comment: Maybe you want $y=x(1-p)^{1/n}$?

Answer (score 0):

From your equation and graph I believe that your independent variable (the one on the horizontal axis) is $n$, and $0<p<1$.

One way to get the kind of graph you want is
$$y=b-(1+p)^n$$
where $b$ is the $y$-intercept of the horizontal asymptote above the graph. You will probably need to shift the graph to the right, as in
$$y=b-(1+p)^{n-a}$$
where $a$ is the amount of shift to the right.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, but I don't know how to solve this. Let me put some more info here.                                          I have: y=x*(1-p)^n  y= 0.0089 and x= 0.0588 n=11  (n goes from 1 to 11)   If I use exponetional growth formula I get the following: 0.0089=0.0588*(1-p)^11 and from this p=0.15  When I have P it's easy for me to calculate y for each n (n1, y for n2 etc.)But in this case the values of y for each n in the begining decreases fast and than slover, and I want it to be slower and than faster.The graps I used are in question are just examples to discribe my problem.

Comment: I think what @Rory Daulton said is totally correct in your case. If you [graph it online](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rpri8rnedj) you get exactly what you wanted, with the $p=0.15$ (change the other values as you wish).

Answer (score 0):

If one starts with $f(x) = 2^x$

Step 1: Reflect across the $x$ axis: $-f(x)$

Step 3: Translate by required amount $T_{-a, b}$: $-f(-x - a) + b$

[image]